# Jenkins behind corporate proxy

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have configured proxy settings for installing plugins in Jenkins.

Please find the below image.

[image]

But when i try to install plugins getting proxy error.

```
Installing Plugins/Upgrades
Preparation 
Checking internet connectivity
Checking update center connectivity
java.net.HttpRetryException: Invalid response code (407) from URL: https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json?uctest at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.testConnection(UpdateCenter.java:1287) at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.checkUpdateCenter(UpdateCenter.java:1068) at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$ConnectionCheckJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1517) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:112) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

Response code 407 means **Proxy Authentication Required** see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#407

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. I have configured jenkins to use proxy. Please find the screenshot in the question. But the proxy settings are not applied while downloading plugins.

Comment: My question is why jenkins thorwing Proxy error even after configuring proxy settings?

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy might be blocking 'https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json'. Try validating mentioned url in 'Test Url' section